# Interpreting "timethese" results for search algorithms

Tags: perl, search

I'm a little confused by the following results and I was hoping some of you might be able to shed some light on why linear search appears to be faster than both binary and interpolation in Perl.

```
Benchmark: timing 1000000 iterations of Binary, Interpolation, Linear...
    Binary: 17 wallclock secs (16.33 usr +  0.00 sys = 16.33 CPU) @ 61236.99/s (n=1000000)
Interpolation:  4 wallclock secs ( 3.65 usr +  0.00 sys =  3.65 CPU) @ 273972.60/s (n=1000000)
    Linear:  2 wallclock secs ( 1.52 usr +  0.00 sys =  1.52 CPU) @ 657894.74/s (n=1000000)
```

Each of the functions are below. I'm trying to write a bunch of well known algorithms and following along in *Mastering Algorithms with Perl*.

```perl
sub LinearSearch {
    # Search linearly for a value
    my $val = $_[0];
    my $arrptr = $_[1];

    for (my $i=0; $i<ARR_LENGTH; ++$i) {
        if ($arrptr->[$i] == $val) {
            return $i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}


sub BinarySearch {
    my $val = $_[0];
    my $arrptr = $_[1];

    my $low = 0;
    my $high = ARR_LENGTH;  # to be modified

    while ($low <= $high) {
        my $middle = int(($low + $high) / 2);
        my $midValue = $arrptr->[$middle];

        if ($midValue < $val) {
            $low = $middle + 1;
        } elsif ($midValue > $val) {
            $high = $middle - 1;
        } else {
            return $middle;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}


sub InterpolationSearch {
    my $val = $_[0];
    my $arrptr = $_[1];

    my $low = 0;
    my $high = ARR_LENGTH;  # to be modified

    while ($val >= $arrptr->[$low] && $val <= $arrptr->[$high]) {
        # solve for the middle value again
        my $middle = int($low + ($high - $low)*(($val - @{$arrptr}[$low]) 
            / (@{$arrptr}[$high] - @{$arrptr}[$low] + 1)));

        my $middleVal = $arrptr->[$middle];

        if ($middleVal < $val) {
            $low = $middle + 1;
        } elsif ($middleVal > $val) {
            $high = $middle - 1;
        } else {
            return $middle;
        }
    }
    return -1;      # Not found
}
```

Additionally, `ARR_LENGTH` is defined as

```
use constant ARR_LENGTH => 10_000;
```

at the outset. It's really just odd that a binary search would take so long, and then interpolation less so, but still twice as long as Linear search.

---

Benchmarking code (just what I found online):

```perl
my @array = OrderedArray();
my $random_val = $array[int(rand(ARR_LENGTH))];
timethese(1_000_000, {
    Interpolation => 'InterpolationSearch($random_val, \@array)',
    Binary        => 'BinarySearch($random_val, \@array)',
    Linear        => 'LinearSearch($random_val, \@array)' }
);
```

where `OrderedArray()` is just a quick (probably unnecessary) function

```perl
sub OrderedArray {
    # Create a random ordered array
    my @arr;

    for (my $i=1; $i<=ARR_LENGTH; ++$i) {
        push @arr, $i;
    }

    return @arr;
}
```

Comment: I never look at benchmarks without the code that produced them. It's too easy to get wrong. Please show your code.

Comment: Tip: `ARR_LENGTH` should be `@$arrptr`

Comment: Tip: `for (my $i=0; $i<@$arrptr; ++$i)` should be `for my $i (0..$#$arrptr)`

Comment: was your array sorted?
Did you count number of iterations happened inside the loop for algorithm?
Are you calling sort each iteration before Binary Search?

Comment: @JayKumarR Yes the array was sorted, believe it or not just an array of the numbers 0..ARR_LENGTH == 1..10000

Comment: You need to show the benchmarking code, too. A common mistake with benchmarks is to change the data without restoring it after each iteration.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I'll add the benchmarking code I guess...it's just what I found online

Comment: @JayKumarR Really? I've ran this code several times on my machine and every one it comes out similar to that above...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass a string to timethese instead of a sub ref, your @array and $random_val variables aren't in the scope where Benchmark evals it.  So it is not actually running with the data you specify.

Try running it as:

```
use Benchmark 'timethese';

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use constant ARR_LENGTH => 10000;

my @array = OrderedArray();
my $random_val = $array[int(rand(ARR_LENGTH))];
timethese(
    -5,
    {
        'Interpolation' => sub { InterpolationSearch($random_val, \@array) },
        'Binary' => sub { BinarySearch($random_val, \@array) },
        'Linear' => sub { LinearSearch($random_val, \@array) },
    }
);
```

Enabling warnings reveals an error in InterpolationSearch.  Enabling warnings and setting $random_val to ARR_LENGTH +1 reveals an error in BinarySearch.  You might consider writing some test cases and validating your code before you worry about benchmarking.

You might prefer cmpthese to timethese; I don't find timethese output as helpful.

Comment: I commented out absolutely everything and got the following results: `Benchmark: timing 1000000 iterations of Binary, Interpolation, Linear...
    Binary:  3 wallclock secs ( 2.47 usr +  0.00 sys =  2.47 CPU) @ 404858.30/s (n=1000000)
Interpolation:  4 wallclock secs ( 3.78 usr +  0.01 sys =  3.79 CPU) @ 263852.24/s (n=1000000)
    Linear:  2 wallclock secs ( 1.44 usr +  0.00 sys =  1.44 CPU) @ 694444.44/s (n=1000000)`
I don't know what else it was running (I didn't have any unordered arrays), but whatever that did, it worked

Comment: no idea what you mean by "commented out absolutely everything", but your numbers are still improbably fast.  added code to run the benchmark correctly.

Comment: Thank you, this solved it. I may have been a little hasteful earlier, but you've still answered the question in full.

Answer (score 1):

The issue of why your timings are not as you expect has been answered, but I thought you may like to see a more *Perlish* implementation of your three search algorithms, together with their timings

Note that all of the functions offered by `Benchmark` are able to take a negative number for their first parameter, which indicates the number of seconds to run each benchmark. It's often a better way of prescribing the number of executions instead of guessing whether you need 100,000 or 1 million for a decent sample

Note also that I've set `ARR_LENGTH` to 1 million

As you expected, the linear search is slowest at 15 searches per second, followed by the binary search at 117,018 per second, and the interpolation search at 481,320 per second

I hope this helps

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Benchmark 'timethese';

use constant ARR_LENGTH => 1_000_000;

STDOUT->autoflush;

my @array = ( 0 .. ARR_LENGTH-1 );

timethese(-10, {

    interpolation_search => sub {
        my $random_val = int rand @array;
        my $i = interpolation_search($random_val, \@array);
        die "Wrong result" unless $array[$i] == $random_val;
    },

    binary_search => sub {
        my $random_val = int rand @array;
        my $i = binary_search($random_val, \@array);
        die "Wrong result" unless $array[$i] == $random_val;
    },

    linear_search => sub {
        my $random_val = int rand @array;
        my $i = linear_search($random_val, \@array);
        die "Wrong result" unless $array[$i] == $random_val;
    },

} );


sub linear_search {

    my ($target, $array) = @_;

    for my $i ( 0 .. $#$array ) {

        return $i if $array->[$i] == $target;

        last if $array->[$i] > $target;
    }

    return;
}


sub binary_search {

    my ($target, $array) = @_;

    my $low = 0;
    my $high = $#$array;

    my ($mid, $mid_val);

    while ( $low <= $high ) {

        $mid = int(($low + $high) / 2);

        $mid_val = $array->[$mid];

        return $mid if $mid_val == $target;

        if ( $mid_val < $target ) {
            $low = $mid + 1;
        }
        else {
            $high = $mid - 1;
        }
    }

    return;
}


sub interpolation_search {

    my ($target, $array) = @_;

    my $low  = 0;
    my $high = $#$array;

    while () {

        my ($low_val, $high_val) = @{$array}[$low, $high];

        if ( $low_val == $high_val) {
            last unless $low_val == $target;
            return $low;
        }
        last if $target < $low_val or $target > $high_val;

        my $delta_i = $high     - $low;
        my $delta_v = $high_val - $low_val;

        my $mid = $low + ($target - $low_val) * $delta_i / $delta_v;
        my $mid_val = $array->[$mid];

        return $mid if $mid_val == $target;

        if ( $mid_val < $target ) {
            $low = $mid + 1;
        }
        else {
            $high = $mid - 1;
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

#### output

```
Benchmark: running binary_search, interpolation_search, linear_search for at least 10 CPU seconds...
binary_search: 10 wallclock secs (10.53 usr +  0.00 sys = 10.53 CPU) @ 117018.33/s (n=1232320)
interpolation_search: 10 wallclock secs (10.39 usr +  0.00 sys = 10.39 CPU) @ 481320.50/s (n=5000920)
linear_search: 10 wallclock secs (10.05 usr +  0.00 sys = 10.05 CPU) @ 15.03/s (n=151)
```

Comment: eww for `return;` instead of `return undef;` (or -1 as the original had)

Comment: @Borodin it's worth noting that this is perfect data for for the interpolation search.  on some data it could be much slower than binary search

Comment: Thank you, this is most helpful!

Comment: @ysth: Does your rather odd ***"eww"*** indicate disapproval? A bare `return` is the proper way to return a failure status, as it evaluates to ***false*** in both list and scalar context. `return undef` in list context returns the one-element list `( undef )`, which is ***true***, while `return -1` evaluates as ***true*** in either context

Comment: Yes, disapproval.  With a function like this, that by nature is asking for a scalar, it should consistently return a scalar.

Comment: @ysth: Unsurprisingly, I disagree. By *"asking for a scalar"* do you mean *expected to return a scalar?

Comment: Also, I wanted to say that I looked into the underscores in numbers that you used (it wasn't something that I've come across in other languages). Perl is full of these neat little syntax treats that are really helpful!

Answer (score -2):

```
use constant ARR_LENGTH=>10000;
for $i (0..ARR_LENGTH) {
   $arr[$i]=int(rand(15000));
}
@arr = sort {$a <=> $b}(@arr);

for $i (0..ARR_LENGTH) {
   $x=int(rand(15000));
   #LinearSearch(\@arr,$x); -- uncomment this or next
   #BinarySearch(\@arr,$x);
}
```

I tested the code with uncommenting one or other. The results were consistent:

```
Jay-$ vim some.pl ( uncommenting Binary Search)
Jay-$ time perl some.pl

real    0m0.096s
user    0m0.087s
sys     0m0.007s
Jay-$ time perl some.pl

real    0m0.091s
user    0m0.083s
sys     0m0.007s
Jay-$ time perl some.pl

real    0m0.100s
user    0m0.091s
sys     0m0.007s

Jay-$ vim some.pl ( uncommenting Linear Search)
Jay-$ time perl some.pl

real    0m23.163s
user    0m23.121s
sys     0m0.032s

Jay-$ time perl some.pl

real    0m22.482s
user    0m22.448s
sys     0m0.025s
```

Conclusion: Binary search is 200 times faster for n = 10000. Well matches o(log n).
If you had run for one million times as you have specified, it is technically 5 billion iterations for linear search which is not possible in 2 seconds you specified. Also the random number you passed, is it well distributed random?

Comment: `sort @array_of_integers` doesn't do what you apparently think it does

Comment: *"Well matches o(log n)"* That is impossible to determine. It could even be *slower* and still be O(log n)

Comment: the original question showed 'timethese' output.   mob was trying to help you; I think his wording was intended to be playful, not arrogant.  Borodin is correct; you can't say it matches o(log n) by comparing different algorithms, you have to show the *same* algorithm with different n scaling that way.

Comment: `perl -E '@a=(6..15);say for sort @a'`.  Binary search and interpolation search depend on the input being sorted, so your results are fast but wrong. Take a deep breath. It's only internet points.

Comment: I have asked for moderator intervention on your toxic comments. It looks to me like you are far more guilty yourself of the negativity that you accuse others of. Please moderate your words. Your answer is a poor one and deserves the downvotes that it got